# Spell weaving mastery. What does it apply to?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Spell weaving mastery](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_Weaving_%28Season_Four_Mastery%29):

> Damaging an enemy champion with an auto-attack increases your spell
>   damage by 1%, stacking up to 3 times (max 3% damage increase)

**What is defined as "spell damage" for this mastery?**

- Does it refer to damage type (true physical magic) or any damage from
  abilities?
- If it refers to ability damage, does the ability have to be castable?
- What about item actives like hextech gunblade?

**I would appreciate if the answers are not based on guesses but rather on testing.**

(I have done some tests; for example Vayne's W isn't affected, neither is sunfire or Teemo E while Cutlass's active is affected. Unless someone comes up with a valid answer, I will be doing some more tests in the following days and post my findings.)

Comment: Don't really get the downvote here... Perfectly valid question.

Comment: Gonna guess that a downvote would be because theyre asking for people to test it, and not just testing it themselves

Comment: I'm with @BenCraig.  OP is being picky and asking people to test their answers rather than doing it himself.  If he answers his own question with his testing results then everything is fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all answerers have in fact done "a minimum amount of testing" and drawn a conclusion "that is *probably* correct" based on that testing. Just because it turns out "*probably* correct" is in fact not correct in this case doesn't mean they did no testing and simply assuming this is quite rude towards the people who put effort into providing you with an answer. The way you're reacting to people's answers is neither constructive nor appropriate (the latter being my personal opinion). Instead of talking down their answers, you should support them in correcting their answers.

Comment: @scenia I am assuming they did no tests because in LoL there are about 2 testable items with active damage Cutlass and Frostqueen (Hydra cant be reliably tested, and from Cutlass are built 2 more similar items). That's not much to test now, is it? Their 3 minute effort isn't helping anyone when they are presenting wrong answers. Support them how? By doing those tests for them then telling them to include the results in *their* answer? Feel free to [join the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25223/discussion-between-user-5061-and-frank).

Answer (score 2):

### Results

AFFECTED:

- Spells that can be cast or activated. This includes passive damage from castable spells (e.g. Jax R and Chogath E).
- Physical damage spells are considered.. spells (e.g. Urgot Q,E, Jax Q).
- Item actives (e.g. Cutlass)<sup>2</sup>.

NOT AFFECTED:

- Item passives (e.g. Sunfire).
- Passive damage from non castable abilities (e.g. Teemo E, Twisted Fate E).
- True damage (e.g. Vayne W, Velkoz spells).
- Pet damage (e.g. Shaco boxes, Heimer turrets)<sup>1</sup>.
- On hit spells (e.g. Shaco Q)<sup>2</sup>.

---

**Notes:**

There are about 120 champions in LoL with 4 spells each. That would be a total of about 500 spells. Testing them all is impossible so I tested enough (hopefully) as to draw a conclusion.

I tested Urgot, Heimer, Shaco, Velkoz, Teemo, Twisted Fate, Jax, Chogath, Vayne, and will do some more testing in the following days. In case you find anything that contradicts the above conclusions let me know so that I can verify it and edit the answer accordingly.

<sub>1: I have not tested Zyra plants, and they might behave differently than other pets.</sub>
<sub>2: I ll test a few more of those.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Spell damage refers to damage that comes directly from a cast ability.  Item actives like hextech gunblade should count as spell damage, but may not be thanks to LoL having notoriously inconsistent code.  Spell damage is not damage that comes from AA modifiers or on hit.

Comment: ".. but may not be..." - Do you mean that it doesn't trigger on gunblade, or that it is not certain if it does?

Comment: It's not certain.  It's active is considered a spell, but LoL has buggy code so its possible that despite being considered a spell, the hextech active doesn't benefit from spell weaving.

Comment: Item actives like Gunblade **should** could as spell damage?  Is this your personal opinion that it should?

Comment: I would appreciate if answers are **not based on personal opinion** (as stated in my question).

Comment: I when I say **should**, I mean that it should work by all logical reasoning but may not actually work due to a bug in the code.

Comment: @sommerjj That implies that you have not tested it, meaning that you arent presenting facts. Here is a fact. I tested gunblade for 20 minutes (along with other spells) and spell weaving applies to it.

Comment: @sommerjj I fail to see the logical reason that it should work besides it being your personal opinion that is the case.  Why would it be a bug in the code if it doesn't?  Just because you **think** something should work a certain way and it doesn't, doesn't make it a bug in the code.

Comment: The amount of hate on this question is insane. Guys, what's wrong? If his answer is inaccurate, either edit it or downvote it. Don't just verbally assault him because of his questionable choice of words. This is not a forum where you throw all kinds of nasty comments at each other.

Answer (score -1):

Everything you have to activate and shows an immediate effect. Thing like Teemos E or Cho Gath's E do NOT count since these are On-Hit. Even though you can activate Cho Gath's E, it does not show an immediate effect.

Also, Skills which don't deal dmg will not apply spell weaving. An example would be Bards ultimate or Anivias Wall.

Any items, no matter if activateable or permanently active, will not apply Spell Weaving.

Comment: None of these informations is incorrect if nothing changed since 5.8. If it is, feel free to correct it.

Comment: I tested today cutlass active (among other things), and it was affected from the mastery. Because of this mistake I cant tell for sure if any of the information you provide is the result of testing or not. Don't get me wrong, you might be providing excellent answers, but often on this site i see highly voted wrong answers, and i am merely trying to avoid that. :)

Comment: @user5061 Don't forget right answers can become wrong if something changes in the game. The nature of video games, especially online ones, makes them susceptible to changes in mechanics or specific interactions. That's why there is the possibility to edit answers. If you find one that's highly voted but wrong, chances are something changed, the author didn't notice or forgot about his answer, and you should probably edit the answer in question so it's correct once more.